# How to redirect the login page and check for login session in Django userena

Tags: django

I am new to django and to userena. I have implemented django userena and the login page which is working fine. Currently after successful login the user is redirected to profile page. I want to change this and do two things:
1. Redirect the user to the home page after successful login and not profile page and second
2. The homepage and all other pages should detect the user session and use the session variables for the particular user to customize the page. 
Please let me know how should I achieve this.

THanks!

Comment: Userena has a bunch of settings you can add to the settings.py.
USERENA_SIGNIN_REDIRECT_URL = ''

Comment: Hi Charl Thanks! that only helps me to set the right redirect. But how do i make sure the session is carried on from this redirect page to another and so on.

Comment: the user should always be available and you could do things like self.request.user.is_authenticated() in a view or {{ user.is_authenticated  }} in a template

Comment: Thanks a ton Charl. Its working now :) Also how do I access the name or any other profile parameters. I tried profile.user.get_full_name it is not helping.

Comment: What error do u get. get_full_name is a function so when it is called outside of a template it should be. profile.user.get_full_name()

Comment: So when I am on the redirected page profile.user.get_full_name this works inside the template and I see the name. But when I browse to a new page the user.is_authenticated is true but profile.user.get_full_name returns a null value.

Comment: did you set the profile value (i.e {% with profile=user.get_profile %}{{profile.user.get_full_name}}{% endwith %}) or you could use
{{ user.get_full_name }} in the template

Comment: {% with profile=user.get_profile %}{{profile.user.get_full_name}}{% endwith %})  worked. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

To redirect use:

```
USERENA_SIGNIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'your_url'
```

the user should always be available and you could do things like self.request.user.is_authenticated() in a view or {{ user.is_authenticated }} in a template

Answer (score 0):

This is how am I doing it to check if the user is signed in.

```
#views.py
from userena.views import signup, signin

def sign_up(request):
    #if user is authenticated, redirect to user's profile page
    #otherwise use userena signup view, with my own form,SignupFormExtra, instead of userena's

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = request.user.username
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/'+username)
    else:
        return signup(request,signup_form=SignupFormExtra)

def sign_in(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = request.user.username
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/'+username)
    else:
        return signin(request)
```

and in my urls.py I have

```
url(r'^accounts/signup/$', 'accounts.views.sign_up'),
url(r'^accounts/signin/$', 'accounts.views.sign_in'),
```